# Cant download Images From Unsplash Website

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, web-scraping, download

Good Evening Everyone

So I am trying to download all wallpaper images from unsplash, got their API link from the network tab in Firefox. (It loads only 30 links per page which is fine)

EDIT: now I Am getting 30 SAME Images but with different names in my folder. Can Anyone Please Help :)

Here is the API link from network Tab: [API Network Tab Link](https://unsplash.com/napi/topics/wallpapers/photos?page=1&per_page=30)

Here is my Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os

with open ("Unsplash.json",encoding="UTF-8") as f:
 s = json.load(f)
    

U = pd.json_normalize(s)


U.rename(columns={'alt_description':'Name','urls.raw':'Links'},inplace=True)
Links = U["Links"].tolist()
Name = U["Name"].tolist()

# 1. Works Fine

for Index,l in enumerate(Links):
 data = requests.get(l).content
 with open ("Unsplash_Pics//" + str(Index) + ".jpg","wb") as f:
  f.write(data) 

# 2. i get Same image 29 times but with different names :(

for l in Links:
 data = requests.get(l).content
 for name in Name:
  with open ("Unsplash_Pics//" + str(name) + ".jpg","wb") as f:
   f.write(data)
```

Comment: ``("Unsplash_Pics//" + ".jpg"`` - you are always using the same filename (".jpg") for all your images in the loop.

Comment: hi i changed my code, can you please check. The first one works fine with enumerate, then helps to number the 30 images, but now i want to name them and am having problems. :(

Comment: cross-posted on [python-forum.io](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Cant-Download-Images-from-Unsplash-Website)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this to fix the naming issue?

```
for Index,l in enumerate(Links):
    data = requests.get(l).content
    with open ("Unsplash_Pics//" + str(name[Index]) + ".jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
```